# What does the pressure sensor measure?

Tags: touchscreen, sensors

What kind of pressure does it measure? Air pressure? Finger pressure on the touchscreen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some devices, like the Motorola [Xoom](http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Consumers/xoom-android-tablet/us-en/techspecs.html), the Sony Ericsson [Xperia Active](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/corporate/press/pressreleases/pressreleasedetails/xperiaactivefinal-20110622) and the Galaxy Nexus, have an air pressure sensor built into them that measures the barometric air pressure. I have the [Barometer HD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.guildsoftware.barometer) app installed on my Xoom which seems to give roughly the same reading as my Suunto electronic barometer.

Support for a barometer pressure (and other environmental) sensor was [added in Android 2.3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/whats-new-in-android-2-3-gingerbread) To follow the trend of linking to the related developer resource, I believe this is a [TYPE_PRESSURE sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html).

See also this related StackOverflow question [Android devices with pressure sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141390/android-devices-with-pressure-sensor), and this [Gizmodo article](http://gizmodo.com/5851288/why-the-barometer-is-androids-new-trump-card) for some of the possible uses for the barometer, which includes helping the device  to calculate your [altitude in GPS apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/gps-calibration/4431#4431).

Android Engineer Dan Morrill made a [post to Google+ explaining why the Galaxy Nexus had a barometer](https://plus.google.com/+DanMorrill/posts/jVJhPyouWDP) internally:

> I've seen a lot of hay made about the barometer in Galaxy Nexus.
>   Here's the skinny; it's not really as dramatic or weird as people
>   think.
>
> The primary purpose of the barometer is (at least, I've been told) to
>   make GPS lockons faster. Locking on to a GPS involves numerically
>   solving a 4-dimensional set of linear equations -- 3 dimensions in
>   space, and time. (Yes, you get accurate time for free if you lock on
>   to GPS.) Because of the way GPS works, this can take a few minutes.
>
> This goes much faster if you already have an estimate of your
>   location. This is why "aGPS" (assisted GPS) services are so popular:
>   by starting with a rough city-level coordinate fix through something
>   like cell-tower network location, you can reduce the amount of math
>   you have to do to lock on. This is where the barometer comes in.
>
> The 3 dimensions in space are latitude, longitude... and altitude. The
>   barometer gives you a reasonable first-cut estimate for altitude. This
>   gives you a bit of a leg up on one of the dimensions -- especially
>   combined with "2D" aGPS -- which can help speed up lock-on in general.
>
> Now of course, the barometer can also be used for things like, well,
>   determining atmospheric pressure (although I'm not sure it's really
>   weather grade.) But the main reason it's in your phone is to help with
>   GPS.

Answer (score 0):

It measures finger pressure on the touchscreen.

Source: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29)

Comment: Why do you think that the pressure sensor does the same thing as the getPressure(int) function? Especially since the sensor doesn't take an int to get a specific location.

Comment: Yes, if we want to get pedantic, you can have an arbitrary pressure sensor that senses anything and extends `android.hardware.Sensor`. But in the end, 99.999% of devices out there provide a pressure reading for the pressure of the finger on the touchscreen.